# Написать программу, которая считывает с клавиатуры количество строк и столбцов двумерного массива

Tags: c

Написать программу, которая считывает с клавиатуры количество строк и столбцов двумерного массива, располагает массив в динамической памяти, считывает элементы массива с клавиатуры, вычисляет суммы строк и записывает эти суммы в новый массив.

Comment: не могу понять как сделать, чтобы можно было вводить определенное кол-во элементов масива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем сообщении нет конкретного вопроса. Формулируйте точнее, пожалуйста.

Массив же динамический подразумевается. Спокойно вводите с клавиатуры, выделяете память (не забыв её очистить в конце) и работаете. Вот пример решения (array - двумерный массив, roswSums - одномерный массив с суммами строк):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    unsigned rowsNumber, columnsNumber;
    unsigned** array;
    unsigned* rowsSums;

    printf("Type the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%u", &rowsNumber);

    if (rowsNumber < 1) {
        puts("The number of rows should be greater then 0.");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Type the number of columns: ");
    scanf("%u", &columnsNumber);

    if (columnsNumber < 1) {
        puts("The number of columns should be greater then 0.");
        return -1;
    }

    array = malloc(rowsNumber*sizeof(unsigned));
    rowsSums = malloc(rowsNumber*sizeof(unsigned));

    for (unsigned i=0; i<rowsNumber; i++) {
        array[i] = malloc(columnsNumber*sizeof(unsigned));
    }

    for (unsigned i=0; i<rowsNumber; i++) {
        rowsSums[i] = 0;
        for (unsigned j=0; j<columnsNumber; j++) {
            printf("Type the (%u, %u) element: ", i, j);
            scanf("%u", &array[i][j]);
            rowsSums[i] += array[i][j];
        }
    }

    puts("Your array is:");
    for (unsigned i=0; i<rowsNumber; i++) {
        for (unsigned j=0; j<columnsNumber; j++) {
            printf("%u ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    puts("Sums for each row are:");
    for (unsigned i=0; i<rowsNumber; i++) {
        printf("%u ", rowsSums[i]);
    }


    for (unsigned i=0; i<rowsNumber; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }

    free(array);
    free(rowsSums);

    return 0;
}
```